# Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(.jpg) failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to randomize background pic and generate some text on it.
So here is piece of my code:

```
$background=$option.".jpg";
$opt="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
$opt=explode(",",$opt);
$option=$opt[rand(0,7)];
```

and

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ($background);
```

Please tell me why I get this error while rand?!?

Pics are numbers 0-7.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you create `$option` before `$background`? On a different note.. Are you referring to the correct directory?

Comment: It's not a cryptic error message, here's the key part: **No such file or directory**.

Comment: Use `echo` to know what is the value of $background just before using `imagecreatefromjpeg`. And read the error messages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are trying to use the $option variable before you have actually set it to what you want it.

```
$background=$option.".jpg";
$opt="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
$opt=explode(",",$opt);
$option=$opt[rand(0,7)];
```

Should be:

```
$opt="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
$opt=explode(",",$opt);
$option=$opt[rand(0,7)];
$background=$option.".jpg";
```

Also, why bother with the string? Why not use this:

```
$background=rand(0,7).".jpg";
```

Comment: No he isn't, he's getting it because: _No such file or directory_

Comment: @bono The $backround variable results in ".jpg" because $option isn't set, check the question title.

Comment: Haha, lol sorry. I even mentioned it in the comments myself xD I must have thought this was another question. Sorry dude ;D

Comment: @bono It's fine, but I was ready for an argument :p

Comment: Haha, damn I did the same thing in my comment too. I need to pay attention to which question I'm replying. :P . Actually +1 now ;D

Comment: @Bono - WORKS NOW... I JUST CHANGED $option before $background...
Thanks a lot men!

CLOSE TOPIC!

Comment: @AnteĎražić, you should mark this as accepted then.  Also topics are not closed when solved.  You should really read the site FAQ

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that your script has the correct file paths (echo the  $background), it could be a permissions issue.  Make sure that whatever web server you are running has permission to read the files in question.